# VB.net OnClientClick pass in ID of another div

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following asp repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptResults">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="FileFile Large pdf SearchResult" id="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID%>">
            <a href='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Link %>' style="text-decoration:none">
                <%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).BackgroundHTML%>
                <p style="float:left;line-height:32px;margin:0px"><%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).Filename%></p>                                            
            </a>                        
            <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmation(this);" ID="btnDeleteFile" CommandArgument="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID%>" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Delete" Style="float:right;margin-top:8px;cursor:pointer;"/>
            <a style="float:right;line-height:32px;margin-right:10px">ID = <%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID%></a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


<script>
    function confirmation(sender) {
        if (confirm("Delete file "+ sender.id + "?"))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
</script>
```

I want the OnClientClick to say:

Delete File ######

to do this I need to pass in the id of the parent div, or the content of the `<a>` next to it.

Currently, I have `OnClientClick="return confirmation(this);"`, which passes in the button. SO I could possibly store this information in a field on the button, but I have tried:

```
name="%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID%>"
```

But this does not work. Are there any other variables I can use to store this, or a way to pass a reference to another element within the repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `title` attribute in your button:

```
    title="<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID%>"
```

and then your javascript will be

```
    function confirmation(sender){
      if(confirm("Delete file " + sender.title + " ?"))
        return true;
      else
        return false;
   }
```

be aware that `title` attribute is intended to display a tooltip, so the user will see a toolip over your button. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OnClientClick="return confirmation('<%= DirectCast(Container.DataItem, FileFolder).DocStoreID %>');"
```

And you `JS` would be

```
function confirmation(sender) {
        if (confirm("Delete file "+ sender + "?"))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it did not respond to the client click